# Is there the way to enum all internal docker interfaces?

Tags: bash, docker

I need to extract all network interfaces according to container.
Now I just enum all networks:

```
$ sudo ls -p /sys/class/net | grep -v /
```

This command line results with:

```
eth01
lo
docker 0
veth1240b7e
veth1348577
veth2b45970
veth2c40276
```

And then I can use it in some configuration utilities:

```
$ foo_init $(sudo ls -p /sys/class/net | grep -v /)
```

But I cannot enum containers networks. Is there the way to gather info in format like:

```
veth1240b7e, my_container_1
veth1348577, my_container_2
veth2b45970, my_container_3
veth2c40276, my_container_4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list the used interfaces with command:

```
docker network inspect
```

If you know the network name you can use

```
docker network inspect <name of the network>
```

and you will get `JSON` file where you have container name:

```
 "Containers": {
            "90e1f3ec71caf82ae776a822222a110a3f175954e5bd4222fd142ac9428": {
                "Name": "container1",
                <snip>
```

Comment: Well, that's just part of the work. You would need to correlate those container names with interface names on the host system (via the ip). But docker network inspect is the right start